# MySQL - Fastest/Smallest datatype for 1-9 int?

Tags: mysql, types

Was wondering what is the fastest/smallest way for adding a column in MySQL which contains only one integer value in a range between 1 and 9.

I assume TINYINT(1) is the best?

Comment: Yes, that's what MySQL uses when you try to add a boolean datatype

Comment: phpmyadmin is a management interface for the mysql database. your question is equivalent to asking what kind of gas your steering wheel uses.

Comment: `TINYINT` is the most natural data type.  Whether it is fastest depends on how the column is being used, what you are measuring the performance of, and even on the specific hardware running the server.

Comment: Thanks! So it is allright to use a tinyint for a column that only uses 1 to 9 as integer, or is it better to use ENUM for stroring it as a string?